# Unable to run Test case on Prod Profile

Tags: jhipster

I am on jhispter my prod file is working fine for me.but when i am run junit on prod profile by change on class by @ActiveProfiles("prod")

then i am getting a error on console :-

```
[ERROR] org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@154abc4] to prepare test instance [com.enest.gom.web.rest.UserResourceTest@1d90afc]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Tests are supposed to be run with the "dev" profile : the production profile uses your "real" production database, that's why I expect you must have some database issue.

Can you post your whole stack trace ?

Comment: This is My StackTrace when run test on prod